# При экспорте из Python в .csv 'да' переводится в True, а 'нет' в False

Tags: python, csv

У меня есть условие, при котором программа в консоль выводит строку 'да' или 'нет', но при экспорте в csv это переносится как TRUE и FALSE, но нужно, чтобы переносилось русскими буквами. Как это сделать?

Кусок кода:

```
if 'Бестселлер' in tag:
    bests = 'да'
else:
    bests = 'нет'
myData = [[bests]]
myFile = open('example.csv', 'a', newline='')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(myData)
    myFile.close()
```

Comment: Как вам можно подсказать если вы ничего не показываете?

Comment: Дайте код, дайте первые несколько строк csv. А, я не первый уже.

Comment: Покажите код программы.

Comment: Покажите весь код программы, т. к. предоставленный Вами кусок всё отлично выводит.

Comment: Код выводит таблицу TRUE, а надо, чтобы выводил 'да'